# CNTK continue model training when using BrainScript

Tags: cntk

I'm looking for a way of continuing training a model. My expected workflow would  be roughly:

- Run a first set of, say, 100 epochs of training, `maxEpochs=100` in my config file
- Inspect the model performance in detail
- If not found OK, try for 20 more epochs, by changing to `maxEpochs=120`

If I run CNTK like this, in the second round of training it will say "I see there's a final model already, so I conclude I'm done!"

There is a [page on the CNTK Wiki](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/wiki/Continue-training-from-a-previously-saved-model) about continuing training, but that seems to be inaccurate. It is not enough to copy the models to a new directory - I also need to delete the model that was "final" after the first round of training.

And that deletion of the "final" model in round 1 is exactly what I'd like to avoid (issue caused by a workflow manager that I'm using).

Effectively, I'm looking for a commandline/config switch to tell CNTK "Ignore the final model in the output directory. Just pretend it is not there, and continue training." Is there such a switch?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no such switch. One possibility is to run for 120 iterations in the first place and then use the cv action to evaluate the quality of the model on earlier iterations.